# How to store string in quotation that contains two words?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I wrote the search code and I want to store what is between " " as one place in the list, how I may do that? In this case, I have 3 lists but the second one `should` is not as I want.

```
import re

message='read read read'

others = ' '.join(re.split('\(.*\)', message))
others_split = others.split()

to_compile = re.compile('.*\((.*)\).*')
to_match = to_compile.match(message)
ors_string = to_match.group(1)

should = ors_string.split(' ')

must = [term for term in re.findall(r'\(.*?\)|(-?(?:".*?"|\w+))', message) if term and not term.startswith('-')]

must_not = [term for term in re.findall(r'\(.*?\)|(-?(?:".*?"|\w+))', message) if term and term.startswith('-')]
must_not = [s.replace("-", "") for s in must_not]

print(f'must: {must}')
print(f'should: {should}')
print(f'must_not: {must_not}')
```

Output:

```
must: ['read', '"find find"', 'within', '"plane"']
should: ['"exactly', 'needed"', 'empty']
must_not: ['russia', '"destination good"']
```

**Wanted result**:

```
must: ['read', '"find find"', 'within', '"plane"']
should: ['"exactly needed"', 'empty'] <---
must_not: ['russia', '"destination good"']
```

**Error when edited the message, how to handle it?**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ors_string = to_match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048024/how-to-store-string-between-quotation

Comment: @mousetail True, I couldn't edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `should` list splits on whitespace: `should = ors_string.split(' ')`, this is why the word is split in the list. The following code gives you the output you requested but I'm not sure that is solves your problem for future inputs.

```
import re

message = 'read "find find":within("exactly needed" OR empty) "plane" -russia -"destination good"'

others = ' '.join(re.split('\(.*\)', message))
others_split = others.split()

to_compile = re.compile('.*\((.*)\).*')
to_match = to_compile.match(message)
ors_string = to_match.group(1)

# Split on OR instead of whitespace.
should = ors_string.split('OR')
to_remove_or = "OR"
while to_remove_or in should:
    should.remove(to_remove_or)

# Remove trailing whitespace that is left after the split.
should = [word.strip() for word in should]

must = [term for term in re.findall(r'\(.*?\)|(-?(?:".*?"|\w+))', message) if term and not term.startswith('-')]

must_not = [term for term in re.findall(r'\(.*?\)|(-?(?:".*?"|\w+))', message) if term and term.startswith('-')]
must_not = [s.replace("-", "") for s in must_not]

print(f'must: {must}')
print(f'should: {should}')
print(f'must_not: {must_not}')
```

Comment: I did edit the post, could you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, but you need to clarify a bit what you want the program to do now. You changed your string that you are searching in to just contain message='read read read'. The error you get is because nothing is captured in the regex capture group 1: ors_string = to_match.group(1), this is for your expression: '.*\((.*)\).*'. Your string does not match your regular expression so None is returned (to_match variable is None). You then try to access something on None (.group(1)) which does not exist. If you can specify what you want to do, I can try to help you.